# Combine data of different database backups into single main database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, multiple-databases

I need some information on how I can achieve the below task.

My scenario is: I have different branches of a brand (we can say McDonald) in remote areas where we don't have access to internet for online working.

I have a few branches like 10 branches in different remote areas. All are working offline and independent of each other.

Everyone is using the same database structure. We have 1 HQ at our main location, we will bring our databases backups (for example) from all our remote locations to our HQ (main location) and marge the data into 1 database.

And one more thing is, we can send the data from our HQ to other remote branches, that means we are adding a new Menu Item to our main HQ database and then that data will be sent back to all our remote locations which they can use.

1- Primary keys must not duplicate.

2- Can I use **SQL Server Integration Services** for this purpose?

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

My application is an ASP.NET web application using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Yes I have some ideas of how you could do this. But I suspect knowing that I have some ideas is not really what you want. You want to know details about to accomplish this. Unfortunately that is impossible to do with the amount of detail in your question. To be honest, this project would take multiple weeks or even months to accomplish. It is entirely too broad for on online forum.

Comment: This sort of thing can be done out of the box with [merge replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication), but setting that up is not entirely trivial. Still, it's a good place to start, because any custom solution you'd cobble together for this will probably resemble it before long.

Comment: Isn't there a tool for this task? Like we have SQL Server Import/Export Wizard? I once heard of something for this, but I can't remember that tool.

Comment: There are wizards for setting up replication, but other than that I have no idea what you could be thinking of.